# Convert "flat" datetime using Excel's format options

Tags: excel, datetime, format

I have received an Excel file that contains a number of datetime fields in the following "flat" format:

20150901120844

I need to convert this to a more useful value such as "2015-09-01 12:08:44" using Excel's formatting options.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no formatting option that will adjust your dates for you, in this case.

But you can use a formula in an adjacent cell to reorganize the data into the date / time text you desire.

Let's say that `20150901120844` is in cell A1. Then in B1 you could enter this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,4) & "-"& MID(A1,5,2) & "-"& MID(A1,7,2) & " "& MID(A1,9,2) & ":"& MID(A1,11,2) & ":"& MID(A1,13,2)
```

It will result in this value in cell B1: `2015-09-01 12:08:44`.